# Loading the page content into a modal via AJAX (jquery modal)

Tags: html, jquery

I am trying to create a modal with jquery modal (https://jquerymodal.com/). I wanna load the page content into a modal via AJAX (as it says in example 4). I tried the code below but it doesn't show the modal.

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <a href="modal.html" rel="modal:open">example</a>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.2/jquery.modal.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

modal.html

```
       <div class="modal">
        <p>Second AJAX Example!</p>
      </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

try to change the place of calling jQuery file and place it in the head tag

```
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <title>Document</title>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-modal/0.9.1/jquery.modal.min.css" />
    </head>
```

And then give the link tag an ID

```
<a href="ajax.html" id="manual-ajax">second example</a>
```

and then add the script to the bottom of the DOM (before closing the body tag)

```
<script>
   // Open modal in AJAX callback
   $('#manual-ajax').click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      this.blur(); // Manually remove focus from clicked link.
      $.get(this.href, function(html) {
         $(html).appendTo('body').modal();
      });
   });
</script>
```